# How to commit transaction before raise in mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, logging, triggers, transactions

```
CREATE TRIGGER maindb.before_acc_update
BEFORE UPDATE
ON maindb.acc FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE errorMessage VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE clientName VARCHAR(100);
SET clientName = (select USER());
SET errorMessage = CONCAT('DB Error=> new acc_name value (',
                          NEW.acc_name,
                          ') cannot be null or empty. Old Value is:',
                          OLD.acc_name);
IF new.acc_name is null or TRIM(COALESCE(new.acc_name , '')) = ''  THEN
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO maindb.acc_log_error (old_tz, new_tz, username) values (old.acc_name , new.acc_name, clientName);
    END ;
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = errorMessage;
END IF;
END;
```

Mysql cancels my transaction. I'd like to log to maindb.acc_log_error and raise my custom error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, if you raise a signal in a trigger, it aborts the action of that trigger, including all changes made by that trigge, e.g. your `INSERT` into the log table.

The only way you could keep the insert to the log table after the trigger aborts is to do that `INSERT` as a separate statement before or after your `UPDATE` to `acc` that spawned the trigger.